# Giving people permission to a private sheet through a script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am at the end of my rope. To set up, we just have a Google Sheet, wherein are several buttons that execute scripts. One script of them is that a file is copied from a private sheet. The problem is that I can't put together a code that allows people to copy the sheets to run the script and then remove the permissions.

I would be really grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Assign a `post fetch` to the button:

[How do I execute a google script as 'owner' of a spreadsheet the user cannot view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40618638/16125139)

Publish a web apps woth `doPost` which integrated with the followings:

[addEditor(emailAddress)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#addeditoremailaddress)

[removeEditor(emailAddress)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#removeeditoremailaddress)

Comment: Okey, I have now tried many things. How would be the application possibility in a script? So that person A runs the script and is added via email and then removed again?

Comment: Answer modified. Please check.